# Right concatenate a column in a csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Lets say I have a csv with the following columns:

```
  A        B
   2     1000
  10     1000
 199     1000
9101     1000
```

I am looking to have column A right fill column B to have a result like the following:

```
 B
1002
1010
1199
9101
```

How can I achieve this output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Select-Object` with a calculated property to "merge" the two into one:

```
# Import existing data
$data = Import-Csv path\to\data.csv 

# Create a new property B with the value of the existing A + B
$data = $data |Select @{Name = 'B'; Expression = { [int]$_.A + $_.B }}

# Export to a new CSV file
$data | Export-Csv path\to\new.csv
```